# laravel Missing required parameters for [Route: frontEnd.show.auth.login] [URI: auth/login/{token}]

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel , I have following link in my forgetPasswordController and I need to rout login

```
public function post_set_password(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
    ], [
        'password.confirmed' => "password "
    ]);
    $find_token = $this->check_token($request->tk);
    if (empty($find_token))
        return false;

    DB::table('password_resets')
        ->where('token', '=', $request->tk)
        ->where('status', '=', 1)
        ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHour(1))->update(['status' => 0]);


    $user = User::where('email', $find_token->phone_email)->orWhere('phone', $find_token->phone_email)->first();
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('frontEnd.show.auth.login' ,[ 'token' =>$request->token])->with('success', 'success');
}
private function check_token($token)
{
    $token_find = DB::table('password_resets')
        ->where('token', '=', $token)
        ->where('status', '=', 1)
        ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHour(1))
        ->first();

    if (!empty($token_find))
        return $token_find;
    return false;
}
```

I have the following in my route:

```
 Route::get('login/{token}', 'loginController@show_login')->name('frontEnd.show.auth.login');
Route::post('login/{token}', 'loginController@post_login')->name('frontEnd.post.auth.login');
Route::get('set/password','forgetPasswordController@show_set_password')->name('frontEnd.show.auth.set.password');
Route::post('set/password', 'forgetPasswordController@post_set_password')->name('frontEnd.post.auth.set.password');
```

but I have this error in return redirect()->route('frontEnd.show.auth.login' ,[ 'token' =>$request->token]); where is problem ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @BABAK ASHRAFI  Missing required parameters for [Route: frontEnd.show.auth.login] [URI: auth/login/{token}]

Comment: `$request->tk` is not `$request->token`

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that `$request->token` is not null. You can benefit from null coalescing operator `??` or make `token` optional.

Comment: I get dd and its gives me null ,what should I do ?

Comment: What is your scenario when the token is null? you can make token optinal at route by `login/{token?}` and handle that in the controller.